# Java NoClassDefFoundError with Dynamically Loaded Jar

Tags: java, jar

Here's my problem in generalized terms as I can't post my actual code.

I'm dynamically loading a jar containing package `com.jar`. I'm then trying to load class `com.jar.MyClass` from that jar and call `doThing()` on the newly loaded class. I'm getting a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` when `doThing()` makes a reference to another class that is in `com.jar` and the .class file is in the jar.

Here what I'm trying to do in my code:

```
File jarFile = new File(pathToJar)
URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { jarFile.toURI().toURL() }, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(classLoader);

Class jarClass = Class.forName("com.jar.MyClass", true, classLoader);
Constructor<?> ctor = adapterClass.getDeclaredConstructor(Integer.class);
MyClass newMyClass = (MyClass) ctor.newInstance(1);
newMyClass.doThing(); //At some point in method makes reference to com.jar.AnotherClass
```

I'm at a loss as to why I can load `com.jar.MyClass` but it can't make a reference to other classes in the same jar.

Comment: Are you sure that the error actually comes from the referenced class not being found? As far as I know, failing static initializers (e.g in the other class) can cause similar symptoms too.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace please?

Comment: **Update** So after some debugging I made some discoveries. It looks like when trying to load the second class in `com.jar` that my URLClassLoader is not being considered when trying to load that class. I verified this by debugging in the URLClassLoader.java class, the URLClassPath variable in that class does not seem to consider my created class loader and I can't seem to figure out why.